# Read files in C++

Tags: c++

This is my simple code:

```
#include "C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Documents\std_lib_facilities.h"
using namespace std;

//**************************************************

int main()
    try {

ifstream ifs("C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\raw_temps.txt");
if(!ifs) error("can't open file raw_temps.txt");
keep_window_open("~~");
  return 0;
}

//**************************************

catch(runtime_error& e) {
    cerr<<e.what();
    keep_window_open("~~");
    return 1;
}
```

The `.txt` file is in address "C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\raw_temps.txt".
When I run that, only the `error (" ... ")` function operates and theifs can't open the `raw_temps.txt` file.
Why please?

Comment: you did not escape the "\" with "\\" in string literals

Comment: You cannot run this because this code is not compiled.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this problem is are due to some misunderstanding your use of backslashes as a path separator. Paths in c++ should be written with normal slashes, and not backslashes to prevent errors like those you have done here. This is because a single backslash is used as an escape character, meaning that it combined with the next symbol becomes a new symbol. An example is "\n" for newline or "\t" for tab.

To prevent this, and to make the code run on all platforms, and not just those using backslash as path separator, stick to slash as a path separator.

More information on this can be found [on Marshal Clines C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/backslashes-in-filenames.html)

And, yes, you can make this work with double backslashes, but then you are making a bad habit IMO. Plus that it is two characters where only one is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ignore "\" as it is a wildcard character. Replace "\" with "\".

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
ifstream ifs("C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\raw_temps.txt");
```

To this

```
ifstream ifs("C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/raw_temps.txt");
```

`\` is used to mark escape characters, so unless you use `\\`, the string will not look like what you think it should.  You can see this by using a debugger and breaking on this line.

Answer (score 0):

best option is to keep the file you want to open in the folder of source code and write this

```
ifstream ifs("raw_temps.txt");
```